# Extract tag content from XML using beautifulsoup

Tags: python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

Thanks to the many threads I found here, I managed to do some of what I wanted to do. But now I'm stuck. Help would be appreciated.

So I have this XML file of a few thousand records, from which I want to extract

- The contents of tag 520 (URL)
- The contents of tag 001 (recno) wherever a tag 520 was found

--> So the result should be a list of URLs + recnos.

Bonus points for helping me export the subsequent result to a csv instead of showing it onscreen ;)

```
# Import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
content = []

# Read the XML file
with open("snippet_bilzen.xml", "r") as file:

    # Read each line in the file, readlines() returns a list of lines

    content = file.readlines()

    # Combine the lines in the list into a string
    content = "".join(content)
    bs_content = bs(content, "lxml")


#Get contents of tag 520 
rows_url = bs_content.find_all(tag="520")
for row in rows_url:          # Print all occurrences
    print(row.get_text())

    # trying to get contents of tag 001 where 520 occurs 
    rows_id = bs_content.find_all(tag="001")
    for row in rows_id:
        print(row.get_text())
```

This is an piece of the xml :

```
<record>
  <leader>00983nam a2200000 c 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">c:obg:160033</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20180605143926.1</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">060214s1987    xx                u und  </controlfield>
  <datafield ind1="3" ind2=" " tag="024">
    <subfield code="a">0075992557726</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="1" ind2="0" tag="245">
    <subfield code="a">Sign 'O' the times</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="#" ind2="#" tag="260">
    <subfield code="b">Paisley Park</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">1987</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
    <subfield code="a">2 cd's</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="306">
    <subfield code="a">01:19:51</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="340">
    <subfield code="a">cd</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="500">
    <subfield code="a">Met teksten</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="520">
    <subfield code="a">ill</subfield>
    <subfield code="u">http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.95.131.jpg.rm99991231.51210.17208</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
<record>
  <leader>00854nam a2200000 c 4500</leader>
  <controlfield tag="001">c:obg:157417</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="005">20180725100810.1</controlfield>
  <controlfield tag="008">060214s1984    xx                u und  </controlfield>
  <datafield ind1="3" ind2=" " tag="024">
    <subfield code="a">0042282289827</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="3" ind2=" " tag="024">
    <subfield code="a">4007196101944</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="2" ind2=" " tag="024">
    <subfield code="a">JKX0823</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="028">
    <subfield code="a">IMCD 236/822 898-2</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="1" ind2="3" tag="245">
    <subfield code="a">The unforgettable fire</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1="#" ind2="#" tag="260">
    <subfield code="b">Island Records</subfield>
    <subfield code="c">1984</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="300">
    <subfield code="a">1 cd</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="306">
    <subfield code="a">00:42:48</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="340">
    <subfield code="a">cd</subfield>
  </datafield>
  <datafield ind1=" " ind2=" " tag="520">
    <subfield code="a">ill</subfield>
    <subfield code="u">http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.31.88.jpg.rm99991231.19959.13742</subfield>
  </datafield>
</record>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample from the XML file? To have something to try the code with...

Comment: I just added a sample. So what I would need are the 2 numbers in 001 and the 2 URLs in 520 u

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc,req,utils

html = utils.getFileContent('snippet_bilzen.xml')
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
rows_url = doc.selects('@tag=520').select('@code=u').text
rows_id = doc.selects('@tag=001').text
print (rows_url)
print (rows_id)
```

Result:

```
['http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.95.131.jpg.rm99991231.51210.17208', 'http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.31.88.jpg.rm99991231.19959.13742']
['c:obg:160033', 'c:obg:157417']
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to get data only from records where elements with `tag="520"` and `tag="001"` are present:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('snippet_bilzen.xml', 'r') as f_in:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'html.parser')

data = []
for record in soup.select('record:has([tag="520"] > [code="u"]):has([tag="001"])'):
    tag_520 = record.select_one('[tag="520"] > [code="u"]') # select URL
    tag_001 = record.select_one('[tag="001"]')              # select tag="001"

    data.append([tag_520.get_text(strip=True), tag_001.get_text(strip=True)])

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
[['http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.95.131.jpg.rm99991231.51210.17208', 'c:obg:160033'], 
 ['http://geapbib001.cipal.be/docman/docman.phtml?file=authorities.87.31.88.jpg.rm99991231.19959.13742', 'c:obg:157417']]
```

Comment: That's perfect !! Thank you very much !